# EntityFramework is failing to save changes with no errors

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have an `AppUser` class that is being passed from *C#* into *Angular* and back into *C#*.

The `AppUser` contains a *foreign key* reference to a `Contact`.

The `Contact` object is created and passed back through *Angular*.

However when I call `context.SaveChanges()` the `AppUser` reference to `Contact` is not updated. No errors are thrown. Any idea how to troubleshoot this?

```
DbContext _ic = new DbContext(); //context declaration
public async Task<ActionResult<AppUser>> UpdateUser([FromBody]AppUser au)
{ //BREAKPOINT HERE TO CONFIRM THE au.EmailContact.Id<=0  IT IS
   try
   {
      if (au.EmailContact.Id <= 0)
         _ic.Contact.Add(au.EmailContact); //if contact was changed start tracking the new one
      if (au.PhoneContact.Id <= 0)
         _ic.Contact.Add(au.PhoneContact);

      _ic.SaveChanges(); //generates ID for phone/email contact
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   { //BREAKPOINT HERE
   }
}
```

Comment: And you've verified that `au.EmailContact` and `au.PhoneContact` are both not null?

Comment: Are you `await`ing your call to `UpdateUser()`?  If you don’t there is a chance your app can exit before the task is finished.  Particularly for console apps

Comment: If this is a disconnected context pattern then you might have to tell EF that the entity has been explicitly modified

Comment: @MickyD that's a good point, I forgot to add that if I call _ic.AppUser.Add(au) I get an error relating to it already being tracked. I haven't experimented with update. However

Comment: ...by the way, should your code example read `.SaveChangesAsync()`.  Your `UpdateUser()` method is `async` but there is **no async code** shown

Answer (score 0):

It probably has to do with async await. If you are adding the entities correctly and you are able to select records from _ic.Contact then

```
await _ic.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Good spot, however becuase OP has listed method as `async`, I think perhaps his code has a typo in that he is actually using `SaveChangesAsync` already.  That or he has other async code in there.  Either way, I don't think this is the problem.  Will need to wait for his clarification above